# Mule CXF consuming webservice

Tags: mule

i am creating one webservice in mule using cxf:jaxws-service. This is the url :http://localhost:65042/InsertDocService/InsertDoc, i am ablie to generate WSDL file, but i want to consume this service in mule using cxf:jaxws-client.

```
<flow name="documentumclientflowFlow1" doc:name="documentumclientflowFlow1">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:65042/InsertDocumentumService/InsertDocumentum" doc:name="Generic"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="insertDocumentum" serviceClass="com.integration.IDocumentumInsert" port="80" mtomEnabled="true" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    <outbound-endpoint address="http://locahhost:65042/InsertDocumentumService/InsertDocumentum" doc:name="Generic"/>
</flow>
```

if i invoke this, it's going to Service project and getting erorr like"org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /InsertDocumentumService/InsertDocumentum)". Please any one suggest me how can i solve this issue and how can i consume this service.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the type (`locahhost` instead of `localhost`), it looks like you're trying to use the same address in the outbound endpoint than in the inbound one. I don't think this is what you want to do, as it will lead to a looping re-entrant call that will eventually exhaust the pool threads, block, time out and die in a fire.

So what do you want to do with "documentumclientflowFlow1"? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: david could you suggest me what is the outbound address be?

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial? http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF